# Is Diablo 3 loot system really RNG?

Tags: diablo-iii

Now from my understanding of RNG, it's a Bell Curved chance.

[image: Normal Distribution]

What it means is:

> The overall chance will **shift** with the average.

But from my playing of Diablo 3, it DOESN'T seem so!

If the loot system is truly RNG, then it means that the "normal drop" will be getting better!

Such as dropping Rare Items left and right! And the chances to drop items "on the left end" are significantly reduced!

But I "still" get a lot of blue, white, even gray items!!!

Maybe it because it's the "Standard Deviation" that was increased instead of "Average".

But then hell! You got "even more" chance to drop garbage items then usual!

What's the goodness in that!?!?!?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this question is about, but RNG does not remotely imply a normal distribution.

Comment: Sigh. I'm not saying this is a good question but I can see what OP is trying to ask. I'm going to assume good faith and answer.

Comment: I don't believe any blizzard games use pure RNG. I think they're designed to keep their games interesting. I have seen things with astronomical odds occur in all of their games, which produced interesting outputs. To quote Pratchett, "Million to one chances crop up nine times out of ten"

Comment: Diablo III's loot system *started out* fairly random, but people got very frustrated with progression *especially* after they shut down the Auction House. So the loot system has been highly optimized for class-suitable loot.  Also, Magic Find *is* a stat, however it was found to detract too much from gameplay (people stacking MF gear instead of proper gear) so they all but eliminated MF, and it's now part of Paragon levels and difficulty setting.  Also, keep in mind *this is Blizzard*, and they use an RNG that is sentient, omniscient and hates your guts.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong on many levels. This is not how bell curves or RNG work.

There is nothing inherent about "really RNG" that would imply a "middle result" (your definition of gray as bottom and blue as middle is entirely arbitrary) happening more often in this case.

The percentage chance of a specific item being a specific rarity depends on the difficulty and where it dropped. Those chances are defined in the game code and have nothing to do with normal distribution.

Comment: AFAIK D3 also utilizes loot tables which determine which items can drop at all within a game session

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Also true. I did consider digging up and posting an example loot table but my google-fu failed me.

Comment: Do you guys, especially Studoku, mind if I delete question!?